# How to install PHP in a new directory in Windows

Tags: windows, php

I am using Xampp for a local dev server, I am trying to upgrade it so I can use the latest version of PHP.

I had it installed in my c drive c:\webserver\php

I just installed everything new in a new drive D

d:\webserver\php

I then boot everything up and then I run phpinfo() and it is still showing my old version of PHP and even points to the old php installation C:\webserver\php\php.ini

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the apache config to use the new PHP module instead of the old one?  You're going to need the following in your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "D:/webserver/php/php5apache2.dll"
PHPIniDir "D:/webserver/php/"
```

...or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

PHP (like many other applications) has a set of folders where it looks for the configuration file, [documented in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).